# Why does the z-ultrafilter Stone-Čech compactification construction have the universal property?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

For the notions of $z$-filter, prime $z$-filters and $z$-ultrafilters see [A Prime $\mathcal P$-filter is contained in a unique $\mathcal P$-ultrafilter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397643/a-prime-mathcal-p-filter-is-contained-in-a-unique-mathcal-p-ultrafilter)

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space. Let $BX$ be the set of $z$-ultrafilters of $X$. For each zero-set $Z$, let $Z^*=\{p\in BX: Z\in p \}$, then the sets $Z^*$ form a base of closed sets for a topology on $BX$. Now consider $K$ a compact Hausdorff space and $f:X\rightarrow K$ a continuous function.

If $p\in BX$, it is easy to see that $\mathcal{F}_p=\{Z\subseteq K: Z$ is a zero-set and $f^{-1}[Z]\in p\}$ is a prime $z$-ultrafilter, then using that $K$ is $T_3$ one can show that $F_p$ has a unique cluster point $q$, as prime $z$-filters are contained in unique $z$-ultrafilters in $T_3$ spaces, then define $\bar{f}(p)=q$. I want to show $\bar{f}$ is continuous. To do this, it is enough to prove that for any zero-set $B$ of $K$, $\bar{f}^{-1}[B]$ is closed in $BX$, since $K$ is $T_3$.

I have shown that if $p\notin \bar{f}^{-1}[B]$, then $p\notin (f^{-1}[B])^*$, so I only need to show  ${(f^{-1}[B])^*}^c\cap \bar{f}^{-1}[B]=\emptyset$, that is, $\bar{f}^{-1}[B]\subseteq (f^{-1}[B])^*$, since then ${(f^{-1}[B])^*}^c$ would be an open set such that $p\in {(f^{-1}[B])^*}^c$ disjoint with $\bar{f}^{-1}[B]$. The problem is that I do not know how to prove that $\bar{f}^{-1}[B]\subseteq (f^{-1}[B])^*$.

So, is this true?, and, is there an easier way to prove that $BX$ has the universal property with respect to compact Hausdorff spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a zero-set neighbourhood $Z_1$ of $q = \bar{f}(p)$ (as $Y$ is Tychonoff, these form a base), we need to find a neighbourhood of $p$ that maps (under $\bar{f}$) into $Z_1$). Let $C$ be a co-zeroset (complement of a zero-set) neighbourhood of $p$ contained in $Z_1$ and such that $C \subset Z_1$. Again, this uses Tychonoff. Now set $Z_2 = Y \setminus C$, and now $Y = Z_1 \cup Z_2$, a union of two zero-sets, only one of which ($Z_1$) is a neighbourhood of $q$.

Now, $f^{-1}[Z_1]$ and $f^{-1}[Z_2]$ are also zero-sets in $X$, whose union is $X$ so the union of $(f^{-1}[Z_1])^{\ast}$ and $(f^{-1}[Z_2])^{\ast}$ equals $BX$.

Now check that $BX \setminus (f^{-1}[Z_2])^{\ast}$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ that maps into $Z_1$ under $\bar{f}$.

Comment: This does not answer my question, as you say I need to check that $\bar{f}[BX\setminus (f^{-1}[Z_2])^*]\subseteq Z_1$, but this is equivalent to what I'm asking in the question.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathcal{Z}}\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathfrak{Z}}\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}\newcommand{\q}{\mathfrak{q}}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand{\U}{\mathscr{U}}\newcommand{\V}{\mathscr{V}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}_z}$This is an old post and the OP probably already knows most of what I'll write here, I'm writing this partially for my own sake; I figured out why everything should work earlier today and I'd like to write down my thoughts before I forget them. I only address the OP's specific question about continuity in the final section.

I'd like to note that every detail and claim in this proof works if $z$-ultrafilters are replaced with ultrafilters on the lattice of closed sets of $X$ *except for the proof $\Z(X)$ is Hausdorff*. Similarly, if you just take ultrafilters on $X$ (no topological requirements) you get another compactification of $X$ with the same universal property that again only lacks (perhaps) the Hausdorff condition. Weird.

---

Fix a nonempty Tychonoff space $X$; meaning, it is Hausdorff and completely regular - a point can be separated from a closed set via a continuous function. Define $\Z(X)$ to be the set of all $z$-ultrafilters on $X$ topologised by the base of closed sets $Z^\ast:=\{\U\in\Z(X):Z\in\U\}$ for a zero-set $Z$. Let $\ZZ_X$ denote the lattice of all zero-sets of $X$.

N.B. the "Tychonoff" hypothesis can be weakened to "completely regular" if you don't mind the loss of $\eta:X\hookrightarrow\Z(X)$ being an injection. Continuity, openness and density of $\eta$ still holds, and $(\eta,\Z(X))$ remains a Stone-Cech compactification. A counterexample to injectivity: Let $X$ be an indiscrete space with more than one point. Trivially, $X$ is completely regular, and obviously it is not Hausdorff, not Tychonoff. We have $\ZZ_X=\{\emptyset,\{X\}\}$ and $\Z(X)=\{\{X\}\}$ is a singleton; $\eta$ evidently fails to embed $X$ into $\Z(X)$ - there is a catastrophic loss of injectivity.

If $p\in X$, then $\p:=\{Z\in\ZZ_X:p\in Z\}$ is a proper $z$-filter, obviously, and I claim it is a $z$-ultrafilter. For if $\U$ is a $z$-filter refining $\p$, then there is at least one $Z\in\U$ with $p\notin Z$. $Z$ is evidently closed, so there is some continuous $\phi:X\to\Bbb R$ with $\phi(p)=0$ and $\phi|_Z\equiv1$. $\phi^{-1}\{0\}\in\ZZ_X$ contains $p$, so $\phi^{-1}\{0\}\in\p$; then $\emptyset=\phi^{-1}\{0\}\cap Z\in\U$ which is a contradiction. Thus, $\p$ is maximal.

We may then define $\eta:X\hookrightarrow\Z(X)$, $p\mapsto\p$. I claim this is a dense embedding.

It injects; say $p\neq q$. $\{q\}$ is closed so there is a continuous $\phi:X\to\Bbb R$ with $\phi(q)=0,\phi(p)=1$. $Z_1:=\phi^{-1}\{0\}$ and $Z_2:=\phi^{-1}\{1\}$ are both in $\ZZ_X$; evidently $Z_2\in\p$ and $Z_1\in\q$, but $Z_1\cap Z_2=\emptyset$ forces $Z_1\notin\p$ and $Z_2\notin\q$. We deduce $\eta(p)\neq\eta(q)$.

It is continuous; it suffices to show $\eta^{-1}(Z^\ast)$ is closed in $X$ for all $Z\in\ZZ_X$. Note: $\eta(p)\in Z^\ast\iff Z\in\p\iff p\in Z$ so $\eta^{-1}(Z^\ast)=Z$ is closed in $X$ as desired.

It is open in its image; it suffices to show that if $V\subseteq X$ is open and $p\in V$, then $\eta(V)$ is open about $\p$ in the subspace $\eta(X)$. This is trivial if $V=X$. Else, there is a continuous $\phi:X\to\Bbb R$ with and $\phi|_{X\setminus V}\equiv0$ and $\phi(p)=1$. With $Z:=\phi^{-1}\{0\}\in\ZZ_X$, we have that: $$\eta(V)\supseteq(\Z(X)\setminus Z^\ast)\cap\eta(X)=\{\q:q\in X\setminus Z\subseteq V\}\ni\p$$Is an open neighbourhood of $\p$ in $\eta(V)$, as desired.

$\eta(X)$ is dense in $\Z(X)$; it suffices to show that for any $Z\in\ZZ_X\setminus\{X\}$, $\Z(X)\setminus Z^\ast$ contains an element of $\eta(X)$. Any $p\in X\setminus Z$ will do.

Now we want to verify that $\Z(X)$ is a compact Hausdorff space. To do so, we need to accept the ultrafilter principle: using Zorn's lemma, it follows that any proper filter on $\ZZ_X$ can be extended to at least one ultrafilter.

To obtain compactness, it suffices to show that if $(Z_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq\ZZ_X$ has the finite intersection property, then there is a $z$-ultrafilter containing every $Z_\bullet$ - note $(Z_i)_{i\in I}$ has the f.i.p. in $\ZZ_X$ iff. $(Z_i^\ast)_{i\in I}$ does in $\Z(X)$: applying the ultrafilter principle yields a $z$-ultrafilter containing $Z$ for all nonempty $Z\in\ZZ_X$. Define: $$\F:=\{Z\in\ZZ_X:\exists F\subseteq I\text{ finite},\,Z\supseteq\bigcap_{j\in F}Z_j\}$$$\F$ is obviously a proper $z$-filter, hence it is refined by some $z$-ultrafilter $\U$. Clearly $\U\in\bigcap_{i\in I}Z_i^\ast$, so we are done; $\Z(X)$ is compact.

Lemma:

> If $\U$ is a $z$-ultrafilter and $Z'\in\ZZ_X$ is such that $Z'$ intersects every element of $\U$, then $Z'\in\U$.

Proof:

> Suppose otherwise; suppose such a $\U,Z'$ exists but $Z'\notin\U$. Then it's not too hard to check that: $$\F:=\{Z\in\ZZ_X:\exists K\in\U,\,Z\supseteq K\cap Z'\}$$Is a proper $z$-filter strictly refining $\U$, contradicting the definition of ultrafilter. So $Z'\in\U$ is forced.

To obtain the Hausdorff property, take distinct $z$-ultrafilters $\U_1,\U_2$. Since each cannot be a refinement of the other, there are distinct (necessarily nonempty) $Z_1,Z_2\in\ZZ_X$ with $Z_1\in\U_1,Z_1\notin\U_2;Z_2\in\U_2,Z_2\notin\U_1$. By the above lemma, we may without loss of generality suppose that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are disjoint.
For the first and last time, we will use the fact that $Z_1=\psi_1^{-1}\{0\}$ for some continuous $\psi_1:X\to\Bbb R$ and $Z_2=\psi_2^{-1}\{0\}$ for some continuous $\psi_2:X\to\Bbb R$.

Define $\varphi:=|\psi_1|-|\psi_2|$. $\varphi$ is continuous and, using disjointness of $Z_1,Z_2$, note $\varphi$ is strictly negative on $Z_1$ and strictly positive on $Z_2$. Define $Z':=\varphi^{-1}(-\infty,0]$ and $Z'':=\varphi^{-1}[0,\infty)$. $Z',Z''\in\ZZ_X$ holds, as witnessed by the continuous functions $\max(0,\varphi),\min(0,\varphi)$ respectively; moreover, $Z'\cap Z_2=\emptyset$ and $Z''\cap Z_1=\emptyset$, so it follows that $Z'\notin\U_2$ and $Z''\notin\U_1$.

I conclude $W_2:=\Z(X)\setminus(Z')^\ast,W_1:=\Z(X)\setminus(Z'')^\ast$ are open neighbourhoods of $\U_2,\U_1$ respectively. They are also disjoint; suppose a $z$-ultrafilter $\U$ lies in their intersection, so that it contains neither $Z'$ nor $Z''$. From $Z''\supseteq X\setminus Z'$, it follows that no element of $\U$ can be contained in $X\setminus Z'$; it follows that every element of $\U$ intersects $Z'$; a contradiction by the preceding lemma. This contradiction shows $W_1\cap W_2=\emptyset$ and it follows $\Z(X)$ is Hausdorff.

Finally, we can begin to address the universal property. For a topological space $Y$, define for $y\in Y$ the neighbourhood $z$-filter: $$\N(y):=\{Z\in\ZZ_Y:Z\text{ is a neighbourhood of }y\}$$I say a $z$-filter $\F$ on $Y$ *converges* to $y\in Y$ if $\F$ refines $\N(y)$.

> Lemma: If $Y$ is (nonempty and) compact Hausdorff, then every $z$-ultrafilter $\U$ on $Y$ will converge to a unique point.

Proof:

> Suppose $\U$ does not converge. Every $y\in Y$ then has a $K\in\N(y)$ with $K\notin\U$. Let $V$ denote an open neighbourhood of $y$ contained in $K$. Since $Y$ is a normal Hausdorff space, there is a continuous $\phi:Y\to\Bbb R$ with $\phi(y)=1$ and $\phi|_{Y\setminus V}\equiv0$. Put $Z_y:=\phi^{-1}\{0\}\in\ZZ_Y$. Since $\U$ is an ultrafilter and $Y\setminus Z_y\subseteq V\subseteq K\notin\U$, by the same lemma as before $Z_y\in\U$ is forced; $Z_y$ intersects every element of $\U$.
>
> Note that $(Y\setminus Z_y)_{y\in Y}$ constitutes an open cover of $Y$ with some subcover $(Y\setminus Z_y)_{y\in F}$, $F\subseteq Y$ finite. It follows that $\bigcap_{y\in F}Z_y=\emptyset$. However, each $Z_y\in\U$ so we deduce $\emptyset\in\U$, which is a contradiction. This show $\U$ must converge to a least one point.
>
> Say $\U$ converges to both $p$ and $q$ in $Y$, $p\neq q$. As $Y$ is Tychonoff, there is a continuous $\phi:Y\to\Bbb R$ with $\phi(p)=0,\phi(q)=1$. In consideration of $\max(\phi-1/3,0)$, $\min(\phi-2/3,0)$, we see $Z_1:=\phi^{-1}(-\infty,1/3]$, $Z_2:=\phi^{-1}[2/3,\infty)$ are in $\N(p)$, $\N(q)$ respectively, so are both in $\U$. This again implies $\emptyset=Z_1\cap Z_2\in\U$, which is a contradiction. This shows $\U$'s limit point is unique.

Suppose $Y$ is compact Hausdorff and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous.

Firstly I claim $f_\ast\U:=\{Z\in\ZZ_Y:f^{-1}(Z)\in\U\}$ is a $z$-ultrafilter on $Y$ if $\U$ is a $z$-ultrafilter on $X$. Noting that $f^{-1}(Z)\in\ZZ_X$ for $Z\in\ZZ_Y$, it's clear that $f_\ast\U$ is a proper $z$-filter. Should the proper $z$-filter $\U'$ be a strict refinement of $f_\ast\U$, consider that: $$\F:=\{Z\in\ZZ_X:\exists Z'\in\U',\,Z\supseteq f^{-1}(Z')\}$$Will be a strict refinement of $\U$ by a proper $z$-filter, a contradiction as desired.

Since $\eta(X)$ is dense in $\Z(X)$ and $Y$ is Hausdorff, if there exists a continuous $F:\Z(X)\to Y$ with $F\circ\eta=f$ then this extension $F$ will be unique. It suffices now to show such an $F$ exists. Define $F(\U)$ to be the unique limit point of $f_\ast\U$ in $Y$. It finally remains to show $F$ is continuous (the OP's original question).

---

Fix $\U\in\Z(X)$, put $y:=F(\U)$ and fix an open neighbourhood $V$ of $y$. Since $Y$ is normal Hausdorff, there is a continuous $\phi:Y\to\Bbb R$ with $\phi(y)=1$ and $\phi|_{Y\setminus V}\equiv0$. Observe $Z:=\phi^{-1}(-\infty,1/3]\in\ZZ_Y$ by the same arguments given before and that $Z$ is a neighbourhood of $Y\setminus V$. Define $Z':=f^{-1}(Z)\in\ZZ_X$. I claim $W:=\Z(X)\setminus(Z')^\ast$ is an open neighbourhood of $\U$ and that $F(W)\subseteq V$. If so, then we would be done.

$W$ is certainly open. If $\U'\in\Z(X)$ has $y':=F(\U')\notin V$, we then know that $Z\in\N(y')\subseteq f_\ast\U'$ hence $Z'\in\U'$. From this, it follows that $F(W)\subseteq V$. Moreover, since $\phi^{-1}[2/3,\infty)\in\N(y)\subseteq f_\ast\U$  is disjoint from $Z$, we get to conclude $\U\in W$ too. Done!

---

In this way, $\Z$ is in fact promoted to a functor $\mathsf{Tych}\to\mathsf{CHaus}$, left adjoint to the inclusion $\mathsf{CHaus}\hookrightarrow\mathsf{Tych}$. The quickest way to describe $\Z(f)$ for a continuous $f:X\to Y$ (between Tychonoff spaces) is to say it is the unique continuous extension of $\eta_Y\circ f:X\to\Z(Y)$ along $\eta_X:X\hookrightarrow\Z(X)$.

Fix $f,X,Y$ and define $F:\Z(X)\to\Z(Y)$ through $\U\mapsto f_\ast\U$. Consider $\V:=(F\circ\eta_X)(p)$. $Z\in\ZZ_Y$ is in $\V$ iff. $f^{-1}(Z)\in\p$ iff. $p\in f^{-1}(Z)$ iff. $f(p)\in Z$. We find $F\circ\eta_X=\eta_Y\circ f$. Fix $Z\in\ZZ_Y$. A $z$-ultrafilter $\U$ on $X$ is in $F^{-1}(Z^\ast)$ iff. $f_\ast\U\in Z^\ast$ iff. $Z\in f_\ast\U$ iff. $f^{-1}(Z)\in\U$. Since $Z':=f^{-1}(Z)$ is in $\ZZ_X$, we find $F^{-1}(Z^\ast)=(Z')^\ast$ is closed; it follows that $F$ is continuous.

By uniqueness, it follows $F$ is the unique extension, $F=\Z(f)$. I thought it would be a good exercise for myself to verify directly that $F$ is the  map obtained when you look at the definition via convergence of $z$-ultrafilters.

Fix $\U\in\Z(X)$. We consider the $z$-ultrafilter $(\eta_Y\circ f)_\ast\U$ on $\Z(Y)$ i.e. it is an ultrafilter in $\ZZ_{\Z(Y)}$; we wish to show it converges to $f_\ast\U$. Fix $K\in\N(f_\ast\U)$. $K$ is, in particular, a neighbourhood of $f_\ast\U$, so for some $Z\in\ZZ_Y$ we have $f_\ast\U\in\Z(Y)\setminus Z^\ast\subseteq K$. Define $Z':=f^{-1}(Z)\in\ZZ_X$.

$K\in(\eta_Y\circ f)_\ast\U$ iff. $\eta_Y^{-1}(K)\in f_\ast\U$; the latter consists of all $p\in Y$ such that $\p\in K$ and contains all those $p$ with $\p\in\Z(Y)\setminus Z^\ast$, that is, it contains $Y\setminus Z$. Recall $Z\notin f_\ast\U$, so $Z'\notin\U$. We would like $f^{-1}(\eta_Y^{-1}(K))\in\U$ to be true; we know this at least contains $f^{-1}(Y\setminus Z)=X\setminus Z'$.

As $\U$ is ultra, I know that there exists at least one $Z''\in\U$ with $Z''\cap Z=\emptyset$: else, by the lemma, $Z\in\U$ would follow, which is a contradiction. So $Z''\subseteq X\setminus Z'$; it then follows $Z''\subseteq f^{-1}(\eta_Y^{-1}(K))\in\U$ and that $K\in(\eta_Y\circ f)_\ast\U$ as desired. Done!

---

It's possible to show that for completely regular spaces $X$, convergence of every $z$-ultrafilter is equivalent to compactness and uniqueness of limit for every convergent $z$-ultrafilter is equivalent to Hausdorffness. The compactness statement is not true for general spaces since general spaces may have a sparse lattice of zero sets.

The "unique limits implies Hausdorff" statement follows from the fact that, if the space were not Hausdorff, say $p,q$ could not be separated, then the upward closure of $\N(p)\cup\N(q)$ generates a $z$-ultrafilter which would necessarily converge to both $p$ and $q$, a contradiction. This statement is true for general spaces, but the converse: "Hausdorff implies unique limits" is not. I don't have a counterexample yet though. To see it holds for completely regular spaces, we take a Hausdorff completely regular space - a Tychonoff space - and then we just copy the proof given above for compact Hausdorff spaces, which only ever uses the property "compact Hausdorff implies Tychonoff".

For a counterexample to "Hausdorff implies all convergent $z$-ultrafilters have a unique limit": consider the [plane with two origins](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000066). Denote by $0$ and $0^\ast$ the two origins, as in the link. I claim that the upward closure of $\N(0)\cup\N(0^\ast)$ is a proper $z$-filter and so generates a $z$-ultrafilter, $\U$; it then follows $\U$ converges to both $0$ and $0^\ast$, giving a counterexample. It suffices to show that $Z\cap Z'$ is nonempty if $Z\in\N(0)$ and $Z'\in\N(0^\ast)$. It further suffices to show that if $U$ and $V$ are neighbourhoods of $0$ and $0^\ast$ respectively, then $\overline{U}\cap\overline{V}\neq\emptyset$. Well, for some $n\in\Bbb N$ I know $U$ contains $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2<n^{-2},y>0\}$ and $V$ contains $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2<n^{-2},y<0\}$. Since the subspace topology on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0,0^\ast\}$ is the usual Euclidean one, it's evident that $\overline{U}$ and $\overline{V}$ both contain $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y=0\wedge x\in[-n^{-1},n^{-1}]\setminus\{0\}\}$ and thus intersect, as desired.

About compactness. For a general counterexample, consider any uncountable space $X$ equipped with the cocountable topology. Such a space is never compact. However, I claim $\ZZ_X=\{\emptyset,\{X\}\}$ as corollary of the fact that every continuous $\phi:X\to\Bbb R$ is necessarily constant. Suppose otherwise, that there are distinct $a,b\in\phi(X)$. Put $\delta:=\frac{b-a}{2}$ and consider $X_n:=\phi^{-1}[a+n\cdot\delta,a+(n+1)\cdot\delta]$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$. Note $a\in\phi(X_0),b\notin\phi(X_0)$ and $b\in\phi(X_1),a\notin\phi(X_1)$. It follows that each $X_\bullet$ is a proper subset of $X$ as each will either miss $\phi^{-1}\{a\},\phi^{-1}\{b\}$ or both. Since each $X_\bullet$ is a closed, proper subset, it follows that $|X_\bullet|\le\aleph_0$ is always true. This would imply: $$X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}X_n$$Is countable, which is a contradiction. Given $\ZZ_X=\{\emptyset,\{X\}\}$, it follows every $z$-ultrafilter (there is only one) trivially converges to every point of $X$, despite the failure of the space to be compact.

Now restrict to completely regular spaces $X$.

Proof $1$ for "compactness implies all $z$-ultrafilters converge": say $X$ is compact and $\U$ is a $z$-ultrafilter on $X$ that does *not* converge anywhere. Then each $p\in X$ has some $Z_p\in\N(p)$ that is not in $\U$. $Z_p$ contains an open $W_p\ni p$; pick a continuous $\phi_p:X\to\Bbb R$ with $\phi(p)=1$ and $\phi_p|_{X\setminus W_p}\equiv0$. Put $Z'_p:=\phi_p^{-1}\{0\}\in\ZZ_X$; necessarily: $$Z'_p\supseteq X\setminus W_p\supseteq X\setminus Z_p$$So $X\setminus Z'_p\subseteq Z_p$. Consider that if $Z'_p\cap Z=\emptyset$ then $Z\subseteq Z_p$ is forced, so $Z$ cannot be an element of $\U$ since $Z_p$ is not; hence, $Z'_p$ has nonempty intersection with each and every element of $\U$, and it follows that $Z'_p\in\U$ for all $p$. Define $V_p:=\phi_p^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$ to get an open neighbourhood of $p$ disjoint from $Z'_p$.

By compactness, there is some finite $F\subseteq X$ with $X=\bigcup_{p\in F}V_p$. It follows $\emptyset=\bigcap_{p\in F}Z'_p\in\U$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $\U$ must converge, somewhere.

Proof $2$: (this works for *any* space) let $\U\in\Z(X)$. By a standard Zorn argument, $\U$ extends to an ordinary ultrafilter $\V$. By compactness, $\V$ is convergent to some $p\in X$. $\N(p)\subseteq\V$ will hold; every $Z\in\N(p)$ then has nonempty intersection with every element of $\U$. By the lemma, it follows $Z\in\U$, so, $\N(p)\subseteq\U$ as desired.

Now to the converse, suppose each $z$-ultrafilter on $X$ converges. Fix $p\in X$ and an open $W\ni p$. Again, there is $\phi:X\to\Bbb R$ continuous with $\phi|_{X\setminus W}\equiv0$ and $\phi(p)=1$. $V:=\phi^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\subseteq W$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$, and we see $X$ has a basis given by such $V$. So it suffices to show $X$ is compact w.r.t. this basis, and by taking complements it suffices to show if a family of sets of the form $X\setminus V$ has the f.i.p. then their intersection is nonempty. Importantly, each $X\setminus V$ is of the form $\phi^{-1}\{0\}$, for the same $\phi$, so it suffices to show that if a subset of $\ZZ_X$ has the f.i.p. then its intersection is nonempty.

Say $(Z_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq\ZZ_X$ has the f.i.p. As before, we can pick a $z$-ultrafilter $\U$ containing each $Z_\bullet$. By hypothesis, this will converge to some $p\in X$. Say $Z\in\U$ has $p\notin Z$. There is a continuous $\phi:X\to\Bbb R$ with $\phi|_Z\equiv1$, $\phi(p)=0$; $Z':=\phi^{-1}(-\infty,1/2]\in\N(p)$ by arguments that have gone before and so $Z'\in\U$; then $\emptyset=Z\cap Z'\in\U$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $p\in Z$ for all $Z\in\U$. From maximality it even follows that $\U=\p$. In particular, $p\in Z_i$ for all $i\in I$ hence $\bigcap_{i\in I}Z_i$ is nonempty, as desired.

Note that above we showed "every $z$-ultrafilter converges" implies "every $z$-ultrafilter is principal", for a completely regular space. Obviously the converse holds. This allows for a quicker proof of "every $z$-ultrafilter converges" implies compactness if the space is Hausdorff as well, i.e. Tychonoff, as then $\eta:X\hookrightarrow\Z(X)$ would be surjective hence a homeomorphism, implying compactness. Note the "Hausdorff" part of the "Tychonoff" hypothesis was only ever used to show $\eta$ is injective, and was used nowhere else.

Comment: $T_3$ denotes (Hausdorff) regular space, what you mean is $T_{3.5}$ space

Comment: @Jakobian Oh, I thought $T_{3.5}$ only referred to Tychonoff space (also Hausdorff). Checking again on Wikipedia, I find the notation is a bit ambiguous, $T_{3.5}$ seems to be used for both. I'll edit to clarify, thanks. Fwiw I got interested in z-ultrafilters and bothered to work out the details for this post because of your Mysior plane question (I had never heard of any of this before)

Comment: What I meant is, whichever convention you are using, $T_3$ is a strictly weaker axiom than $T_{3.5}$, in your convention, Tychonoff spaces should be Hausdorff $T_{3.5}$ spaces, not Hausdorff $T_3$ spaces.

Comment: @Jakobian I use Tychonoff as "completely regular and Hausdorff", I thought this was standard

Comment: Yes, that's standard, Tychonoff is synonymous with Hausdorff and completely regular. My point was that $T_3$ means regular while $T_{3.5}$ means completely regular, and regular and completely regular are not the same.